# Codeigniter - Redirect when The URI you submitted has disallowed characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Current I have researched that we can allow special character by editing the config files.

Links: https://hoststud.com/resources/error-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters-in-codeigniter.420/

How do i config my config file that when there is an error , It will direct to another page.

 File that I have edited

> XXX/system/core/URI.php  (Line326)

What I have done:
Added this row : `redirect('index.php/customer/customerHomepage'));`

But there is an error 
Error Message that appeared

> Message: Call to undefined function redirect()

Answer (score 0):

Just load the URL helper before call redirect function:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

If the error persists describe it and I will try to help you.

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected ')'

This is the error i got

Comment: try removing the parentheses, like this: redirect('index.php/customer/customerHomepage');

Comment: Undefined property: CI_URI::$load  , and 2nd error  Call to a member function helper() on null

Comment: try create a .htaccess file in the main application directory, put this inside: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: maybe the error is that in the not allowed characters the dot, then the redirect ('index.php ...') fails